# Check if iterator is sorted

Tags: python, iterator

I have an iterator `it` that I'm assuming already sorted but I would like to raise an exception if it isn't.

Data from iterator is not in memory so I do not want to use `sorted()` builtin because AFAIK it puts the whole iterator in a list.

The solution I'm using now is to wrap the iterator in a generator function like this:

```
def checkSorted(it):
  prev_v = it.next()
  yield prev_v
  for v in it:
    if v >= prev_v:
      yield v
      prev_v = v
    else:
      raise ValueError("Iterator is not sorted")
```

So that I can use it like this:

```
myconsumer(checkSorted(it))
```

Does someone know if there are better solutions?

I know that my solution works but it seems quite strange (at least to me) writing a module on my own to accomplish such a trivial task. I'm looking for a simple one liner or builtin solution (If it exists)

Comment: This never updates `prev_v`; it won't work for `iter([1, 3, 2])`.

Comment: Honestly, this seems good enough. It has decent performance and does what you need (if you update `prev_v`). Why do you need a one-liner?

Comment: Missed a line! Thanks.

Comment: @nneonneo: because it seems strange to me writing a function for such a trivial thing: I'm hoping there is a builtin solution.

Answer (score 4):

Basically your solution is almost as elegant as it gets (you could of course put it in an utility module if you find it generally useful). You could if you wanted it use an infinity object to cut the code down a bit, but then you have to include a class definition as well which grows the code again (unless you inline the class definition):

```
def checkSorted(it):
    prev = type("", (), {"__lt__": lambda a, b: False})()

    for x in it:
        if prev < x:
            raise ValueError("Not sorted")
        prev = x
        yield x
```

The first line is using the `type` to first create a class and then instantiate it. Objects of this class compares less than to anything (infinity object).

The problem with doing a one-liner is that you have to deal with three constructs: you have to update state (assignment), throw an exception and doing a loop. You could easily perform these by using statements, but making them into a oneliner will mean that you will have to try to put the statements on the same line - which in turn will result in problem with the loop and `if`-constructs.

If you want to put the whole thing into an expression you will have to use dirty tricks to do these, the assignment and looping the `iterutils` can provide and the throwing can be done by using the `throw` method in a generator (which can be provided in an expression too):

```
imap( lambda i, j: (i >= j and j or (_ for _ in ()).throw(ValueError("Not sorted"))), *(lambda pre, it: (chain([type("", (), {"__ge__": lambda a, b: True})()], pre), it))(*tee(it)))
```

The last `it` is the iterator you want to check and the expression evaluates to a checked iterator. I agree it's not good looking and not obvious what it does, but you asked for it (and I don't think you wanted it).

Comment: I like very much the idea of an infinite object, but the one-liner solution is somewhat "unwatchable" :) (though it is very smart)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative i suggest to use [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) (and `zip_longest` in python 3 )to create a generator contains consecutive pairs :

You can use `tee` to  create 2 independent iterators from a first iterable.

```
from itertools import izip_longest,tee

def checkSorted(it):
  pre,it=tee(it)
  next(it)
  for i,j in izip_longest(pre,it):
    if j:
      if i >= j:         
        yield i
      else:
        raise ValueError("Iterator is not sorted")
    else :
        yield i
```

Demo :

```
it=iter([5,4,3,2,1])
print list(checkSorted(it))

[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

it=iter([5,4,3,2,3])
print list(checkSorted(it))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bluebird/Desktop/ex2.py", line 19, in <module>
    print list(checkSorted(it))
  File "/home/bluebird/Desktop/ex2.py", line 10, in checkSorted
    raise ValueError("Iterator is not sorted")
ValueError: Iterator is not sorted
```

*Note* : Actually I think there is no need to yield the values of your iterable wen you have them already.So as a more elegant way I suggest to use a generator expression within `all` function and return a bool value :

```
from itertools import izip,tee

def checkSorted(it):
  pre,it=tee(it)
  next(it)
  return all(i>=j for i,j in izip(pre,it))
```

Comment: Are you relying on None comparing <= everything? It's probably better to use an explicit sentinel; comparisons against None don't work like that in Python 3, and I don't think they necessarily work like that in alternate Python implementations.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah it should be `izip` also i mentioned the `zip` in python 3, so we wont have any `None`!

Comment: First, your code still uses `izip_longest`. Second, if you use `izip`, you won't yield the last input element.

Comment: @user2357112 I added an explanation and another alternative for returning the iterable! i think there is no need to yield the items when it would raise an `ValueError`!

Comment: The last solution isn't as nice as the original solution because `tee` internally stores any elements that aren't consumed by all iterators. Since you consume all of `pre` and `it` but none of `main_it`, this basically makes `tee` store all the elements - precisely what OP was trying to avoid!

Comment: @nneonneo As I said in preceding comment there is no need to yield the items when it would raise an `ValueError` so Just we need to return the iterable wen the list is sorted although its pretty an useless approach!

Comment: @Kasra: And when it *doesn't* raise a ValueError? It looks like this function is meant to validate an iterator as it produces elements; we don't get a second pass over the input.

Comment: @user2357112  `if any i < j`

Comment: @nneonneo Yes `tee` stores unconsumed elements, but that doesn't mean that it stores all elements (at the same time). Only one element that has been consumed from the originating iterator need to be stored, after that it is consumed from the second iterator as well and does not need to be stored any more. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: @skyking: Take another look at the last function, which makes 3 tee iterators and only advances 2 of them.

Comment: @user2357112 Indeed! its because i consume the `pre` and `it` within `izip` so if I want to return anything I need to have another iterator already and return it! Or maybe there is some black point that i missed that :( am I right?

Comment: @Kasra: Yes, but that requires storing every element of the input in memory, which as nneonneo said, is exactly what the questioner wanted to avoid.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah i'm agree 100% but i said that it's not a good idea ... anyway I think I should remove that evil suggestion! ;)

Comment: @user2357112 And thanks a lot for taking time and attention!

Comment: @user2357112 Yes I see five iterators: pre, it, the result from `izip`, the anonymous generator (argument to `all`) and the iterator formerly known as `it`, but I don't see the scenario where data is not consumed from all of them in parallell. You see for each element you extract from the anonymous iterator you will extract one element from the anonymous generator which in turn will extract one element from `it` and `pre` which in turn will extract one element from the iterator formerly known as `it`. Have I still missed something important?

Comment: @skyking: The 3-tee solution was deleted. You can see it in a [previous revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31021438/5).

Comment: The first solution does not work as described. You'll get `[5, 4, 3, 2]` response instead and the second solution does not return an iterator at all. Downvoted for that reason.

Comment: @skyking Actually after multiple editing i forget to applied the changes on code (but it appears in result ;) ) . Now it works and about the last code i explained above that there is no need to return the iterator when you have it already!

Comment: @Kasra OK, now that works, but the last "solution" does not actually return an iterator. I don't see any reason to believe that Zac already has the elements, the fact that Zac does not want to put them in a list suggests (to me) that Zac doesn't have them (or they could be put in a list at a quite reasonable cost - if they isn't already). Since the latter is only based on an expressed unfounded assumption I removed the downvote

Comment: Actually I don't have them in a list. I'm using an iterator because I don't want to load alla data in memory. Second solution is definitely not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Zac All of my suggestions are iterators based! abut the second one as i said a million times :) it's just a suggestion you can simply ignore it! and about my code it refuse of multiple assignment that you had in your code! and it just deal with iterators and at this perspective I think it's more efficient!